# How to put Expandable list view inside scroll view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello there i am making a flutter application in which inside ScrollView in need to put Expandable list view.First of all here is my `build` method.

```
  return Scaffold(   
    appBar: AppBar(  
      backgroundColor: app_color,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(  
        color: Colors.white, //change your color here 
      )),   
    //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    //key: scaffoldKey,    
    backgroundColor: app_color,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(  
    child: Container(  
      child: Column(  
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,  
        children:<Widget>[  
          Text("Header"),  
          new ListView.builder(  
            itemCount: datas.length,  
            shrinkWrap: true,  
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {  
              return new ExpansionTile(  
                title: new Text(datas[i].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,                                 fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),  
                children: <Widget>[  
                  new Column(  
                    children: _buildExpandableContent(datas[i]),  
                  ),  
                ],  
              );  
            },  
          ),  
          Text("Footer"),  
        ],  
      ),  
    )  
  )

);  
  }
```

Now the problem is that without `SingleScrollChidView` this works fine But after using `SingleScrollChidView` it does not shows anything and gives error `RenderBox was not laid out`.What is wrong here ? How can i use Expandable list view inside Singlechildscroll view in flutter.

Comment: What widget are you using inside `_buildExpandableContent` ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve Expanded ListView within ScrollView with text by
- Use of `Wrap` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, provided you make all `ListView` using `shrinkWrap: true`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          _textBody, // text body, with 1000+ words
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListViewOne(_genericListDataOne()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListViewTwo(_genericListDataTwo())
            ],
          )
        ],
  ),
    ),
```

part of the Code for `ListViewOne`

```
 ListViewOne(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
  children: // build list here,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `ListView` a fixed height using `SizedBox` or similar

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Header"),// tested with 20 of these for scrolling
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return new ExpansionTile(/* whatever */ );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Text("Footer"),// tested with 20 of these for scrolling
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: doesn't it will restrict expandable list view height ?I mean setting height static will cut the content of expandable list view if i have many items in list

Comment: set height to be a fraction of screen size like 50% or so

Comment: And this will enable you to scroll both the listview and singlechildscrollview

Comment: I have updated the code; listview is now half the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Use SizedBox.expand for this problem,

```
SizedBox.expand(
child : ListView.builder(  
            itemCount: datas.length,  
            shrinkWrap: true,  
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {  
              return new ExpansionTile(  
                title: new Text(datas[i].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,                                 fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),  
                children: <Widget>[  
                  new Column(  
                    children: _buildExpandableContent(datas[i]),  
                  ),  
                ],  
              );  
            },  
          ),  
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer

Try this, you should get the desired output you are looking for.

You can find the output [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BeWZc3P5FaVb8pKX-OnUXhp_Odkb8rVJ)

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
     Text(),
     ListView(
       shrinkWrap: true,  
       physics: ScrollPhysics(),
       children:[]),
     Text()
   ]
 )
```

adding below shown code in ListView will allow smooth scrolling of widget

```
 shrinkWrap: true,  
 physics: ScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Did you try the code you posted? `Expanded` on the `ListView` inside the `SingleChildScrollView` won't work.

Comment: It does not work. Using OP's code and wrapping `Expanded` widget around `ListView` as per your suggestion gives an error: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.` This means you cannot have a scrolling widget with infinite height as a child of another scrolling widget.

Do check the code before posting.

Comment: hi @Doc thankyou for pointing out the mistake, the method followed by the op was the problem after all so I have edited my answer, could please have a look and maybe remove the downvote. Thankyou.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Don't you understand? `ListView` needs to know the bounds for scrolling to work. `ListView` is inside another widget which is scrolling. Scrolling won't work without bounds.

Comment: did you ran the code? I have provided a link for the output, you can refer that, `Expanded()` widget solves that issue where you need to provide the bounds.

Comment: I saw your output. Your end result allows the scrolling on the `ListView` but OP clearly mentions that the `ListView` is inside another scrolling widget. Your code won't let the parent widget scroll.

Comment: in that case we must wait for the op what output does he really looking for.

Comment: Sure. But in the meantime place a lot of `Text` widgets after the `ListView` in your code and see if you can scroll both the list and parent widget to see all the `Text` widgets created

Comment: as per the current layout , parent widget is not scrollable. Only the `ListView.Builder()` under the parent widget is. adding n no. of text field below the listview will simple create less space for `ListView.Builder()` widget to view / scroll in

Comment: Hey @Doc could you remove that negative marking from my answer, as the answer works just fine and it seems op is not active and neither he is replying.